# Incrementally increase non zero elements in a list

Tags: python, list

if i got this list

```
a = [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]
```

and I want it turned into

```
a = [1,0,0,2,0,0,0,3]
```

Comment: What have you tried from your research? What went wrong?

Comment: "That means increase each number 1 based on index?" That isn't really what you're trying to do

Comment: i know, my english sucks a bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setup for solution #1 and #2

```
from itertools import count

to_add = count()
a = [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]
```

Solution #1

```
>>> [x + next(to_add) if x else x for x in a]
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3]
```

Solution #2, hacky but fun

```
>>> [x and x + next(to_add) for x in a]
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3]
```

Setup for solution #3 and #4

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1])
```

Solution #3

```
>>> np.where(a == 0, 0, a.cumsum())
array([1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3])
```

### Solution #4 (my favorite one yet)

```
>>> a*a.cumsum()
array([1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3])
```

All the `cumsum` solutions assume that the non-zero elements of `a` are all ones.

---

Timings:

```
# setup
>>> a = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]*1000
>>> arr = np.array(a)
>>> to_add1, to_add2 = count(), count()
# IPython timings @ i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz (though only relative times are of interest)
>>> %timeit [x + next(to_add1) if x else x for x in a] # solution 1
669 µs ± 3.59 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
>>> %timeit [x and x + next(to_add2) for x in a] # solution 2
673 µs ± 15.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
>>> %timeit np.where(arr == 0, 0, arr.cumsum()) # solution 3
34.7 µs ± 94.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
>>> %timeit arr = np.array(a); np.where(arr == 0, 0, arr.cumsum()) # solution 3 with array creation
474 µs ± 14.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
>>> %timeit arr*arr.cumsum() # solution 4
23.6 µs ± 131 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
>>> %timeit arr = np.array(a); arr*arr.cumsum() # solution 4 with array creation
465 µs ± 6.82 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: I like this, though I'd do it a little differently: https://gist.github.com/jszakmeister/7469cabbc351b7b829198ff34f811d05  I think it's a little too clever otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would do it:

```
def increase(l):
    count = 0
    for num in l:
        if num == 1:
            yield num + count
            count += 1
        else:
            yield num

c = list(increase(a))

c

[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3]
```

Comment: I'm genuinely curious why you'd use `yield` in the function to just call `list()` on it later.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension for this:

```
print([a[i]+a[:i].count(1) if a[i]==1 else a[i] for i in range(len(a))])
```

Output:

```
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3]
```

Loop version:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i]==1:
        a[i]=a[i]+a[:i].count(1)
```

Comment: Oh man, please don't encourage one-liners like this, it's terribly hard to read.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister Okay, i'll add a loop version now.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister Now?

Comment: That's definitely better, though for a large list the `.count()` call is pretty inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to increase each `1` except for the first one, right?

How about:

```
a = [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]

current_number = 0

for i, num in enumerate(a):
    if num == 1:
        a[i] = current_number + 1
        current_number += 1

print(a)

>>> [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3]
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
current_number = 1

for i, num in enumerate(a):
    if num == 1:
        a[i] = current_number
        current_number += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy cumsum or cumulative sum to replace 1's to sum of 1's

```
In [4]: import numpy as np
In [5]: [i if i == 0 else j for i, j in zip(a, np.cumsum(a))]
Out[5]: [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3]
```

Comment: Generally not optimal to mix pure Python comprehension with cumsum. When you find yourself doing that, look into masking or where.

Answer (score 0):

Other option: a one liner list comprehension, no dependencies.

```
[ 0 if e == 0 else sum(a[:i+1]) for i, e in enumerate(a) ]

#=> [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3]
```